# How can I download an HTML webpage including JavaScript-generated content from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, wget, html

On Google Chrome, when we go to the development mode, <kbd>right-click</kbd> an HTML element → *Copy* → *Copy element*, we can copy the HTML content of a webpage. Below is an example of the procedure I've described:

[image: Copying HTML content with Google Chrome]

My problem is that, when I use `wget` for downloading the webpage, I get the source code of the page, including its JavaScript addresses and scripts.

I'd like to use the command line for downloading the final HTML result of a page, just like Google Chrome does in my example. Getting the HTML content that is being displayed on the page would be useful for automating the extraction of information from webpages for me.

Is it possible to download the HTML of a page (not the source code) using `wget` or other command line tools?

Comment: `wget` does not process JavaScript to generate the final rendering of a page. When I have needed to get a complete copy of a site in its current state — more or less — it has been necessary to use a browser extension that executes only after `onreadystatechange` completes.

Comment: It's possible with `python` and `selenium` , but I guess that is more a question for [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) ... However, there are many resources for that online and probably this has been answered before. You will find a lot about PhantomJS, but that project is discontinued. You should use Chromium or Firefox as driver.

Comment: Just to be clear on some concepts here: the difference you are seeing is not between "the HTML" and "the source code" but between the _initial_ response sent to your browser, and the _processed_ result after some client-side scripts have run; and there is no "final" HTML of the page, because the JavaScript could change the content completely every second (or every click), and no version would be any more "real" than the others. That doesn't make your question completely meaningless, but it's worth understanding that there's no guarantee you can get the "real" version of any page like this.

Comment: Duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/q/411540/396228

Comment: @IMSoP I suppose the OP's intent is to have exactly that dynamic behavior in a local copy.

Comment: @sondra.kinsey Actually, the question is different. I said many times in my question that I didn't want to get the source code of the page as it is when on the "View Source Code" of the browser. The solutions on the link won't give me the HTML that I needed in this case.

Comment: @raylight Just to be really clear: there is no difference between "the HTML" and "the source code"; they mean *exactly the same thing*. What you are looking for is exactly the same as the other question, just worded differently: you want to get the HTML structure that you see in the browser *after the browser has run some additional code* which *modifies that HTML*.

Comment: @Raffa why does this site need a separate tag for HTML DOM?

Comment: Cool, I wanna know how to get the CSS and JavaScript files too, but since this is Ubuntu, not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since you have **Google Chrome** installed, you can get the web-page's inner HTML structure by running in the terminal:

```
google-chrome --headless --dump-dom 'URL' > ~/file.html
```

Replace `URL` with the URL of the web page you want. The [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_htmldom.asp) of the page will be saved to a file named `file.html` in your home directory.

Comment: Will this also wait for document readyStateComplete?

Comment: @Nzall Yes, *Google Chrome*  supports [HTML DOM readyState Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_readystate.asp) and `--dump-dom` will do that.

Comment: I had to add `--virtual-time-budget=10000 --timeout=10000 --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --disable-gpu --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"` to get everything rendered properly.

Comment: Indeed, providing a user agent is often necessary, but `--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)"` did the trick. Thanks!