# How to run google-chrome-stable from a remote SSH session on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, ssh, google-chrome

I have installed google-chrome-stable on my Ubuntu 20.04 instance. I also installed a Gnome desktop on this machine.

I know from htop that the gnome-shell is running and working (have tested it using RDP).

However, whenever I remotely ssh and execute

```
google-chrome-stable
[42215:42215:0704/003111.941825:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(247)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[42215:42215:0704/003111.942127:ERROR:env.cc(226)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting
```

**I want it to be able to run google chrome in the gnome-shell from a remote ssh session**. I have tried to update the $DISPLAY to 0.0, but still no luck:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to get this to work?

Comment: What do you need google-chrome for? … Might running it in [headless mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/1321020) be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

when you login remotely, you would need to forward X.

if you use ssh,  passing a parameter -Y  or -X to ssh would work, e.g.,
ssh -Y  $useid@$machine

would allow $userid to have X on the $machine remotely logged into.